# redirect to previous page after logging in or registering

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter. I'm developing a job site.I search a job and find suitable job then when clicking the job detail then if the user is logged in then the apply now button appears but if the user is not logged in then the the login or register button appears. What I need to do is after clicking on login or register when they finish the process then they needed to redirect to the same page that they have searched. How can I do that in cdeigniter?.

my job detail page is

```
public function details($slug = NULL)
{
    $this->load->model('jobmodel');
    $this->load->helper('job');
    $slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $jobID = $this->jobs_model->getJobidFromSlug($slug);
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $check = $this->jobs_model->checkAppliedJob($userID, $jobID);
    $data['check'] = $check;

    // #common head section

    $data['site_title'] = 'Job By Country | Neev ';
    $data['site_keywords'] = 'job,dubai,hr,portal';
    $data['site_description'] = 'Neev  Home, Hr Portal, Job ';
    $join = 'LEFT JOIN job_industry AS ji ON(ji.id = ejp.job_industry) LEFT JOIN job_country AS jc ON (ejp.country_id = jc.id) 
                LEFT JOIN job_category AS jcat ON (ejp.job_category = jcat.id)where ejp.slug ="' . $slug . '"';
    $jobsDetails = Jobmodel::find(array(
        'select' => 'ejp.*,ji.title as industry_type,jc.title as country,jcat.title as category',
        'from' => 'employer_job_posting as ejp',
        'joins' => $join
    ));

    // echo Jobmodel::connection()->last_query;
    // die;

    $data['main_content'] = 'jobFulldetails';
    $data['jobs'] = $jobsDetails;
    $this->load->view($this->jobView, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this logic keep previous page browsed in a session. Once you are logged in or registered get the value of that session variable to redirect to that page. Something  Like this

```
header("location:$_SESSION['prev_page']");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var back = document.referrer;
        window.location.replace(back);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to redirect the user back to the controller using the redirect() method that comes with CI's URL helper?
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html bottom of page

something like

```
redirect('search/foo/bar');
```

I use this all the time. The search controller's behavior determines how your actual redirect link would look. I use _remap() a lot in my controllers.